# C - Reading File with sprintf

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read multiple files. The format of the files would something similar to`YYYY-mm-dd-HH-MM.txt` and for example `2012-11-26-18-50.txt`

I have the following code

```
char text_buffer[1000];
char file_buffer[256];
int year, month, day, hour, minute;
year = 2012; month = 11; day = 26; hour = 18; minute = 0;

sprintf(file_buffer, "%d-%d-%d-%d-%d.txt", year, month,day,hour,minute);
FILE *ptr_file;
ptr_file=fopen(file_buffer, "r");
if(ptr_file != NULL)
    printf("File opened %s for reading.\n", file_buffer);
else
    printf("Couldn't open %s.\n", file_buffer);

line_number = 0;
while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer), ptr_file) != NULL){
    if(strcmp(buffer, "")==0)
       return 0;
    char *views = strok(buffer, ",");
...
}
```

I'm assuming that's all the information needed. I'll post all of it if it's still unclear as to where my problem is.
When I run the program. I get both
`Filed opened...` and `Couldn't open...`. then a segmentation fault.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that call to sprintf()?  Are you trying to create a filename?

Comment: Actually, that call to sprintf() will try to write to the memory location pointed to by file_buffer, and you haven't initialized it.  So it's gonna have a segmentation fault or other error.

Comment: Do the files actually exist?

Comment: With your code as written, it is impossible to get both `File opened...` and `Couldn't open...` errors.  And it makes sense that it would segv if `Couldn't open...` is printed, you need to avoid subsequent code if you detect that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you will want to make sure you do something (maybe return an error code) when you cannot open the file. A segmentation fault will occur when trying to read from a NULL FILE*.

Also, you are corrupting memory since file_buffer is pointer, not a buffer. You need to initialize it to something. Lastly, you want to make sure you close the file you open.

I am also assuming you define buffer somewhere. In your code example I don't see the definition. Maybe you meant to use text_buffer instead?

If you are working with LINUX for these types of memory corruptions I would suggest two tools.

1. GDB, to step through the program a line at time and inspect variables as you go along.
2. Valgrind, which will let you know about simple memory corruptions like this one.

These two tools, once you are proficient with them, can help eliminate most simple programming errors.

Answer (score 1):

`file_buffer` is never initialized, it could point anywhere.  You probably want something like:

```
char file_buffer[PATH_MAX+1];
```

instead of

```
char *file_buffer;
```

Comment: I changed it to `char buffer[512];` and still get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `file_buffer` variable anywhere.

You should initialize it as

```
char file_buffer[256];
```

Answer (score 0):

Format print the date and times, example `%02d`, since they may contain 1-2 digits each.

Comment: This should be comment in the original question.

Comment: @Burgos: I was thinking that the reason he is getting the `Opened file` and `Couldn't open` message was that, as he said, he was reading multiple files and some of them succeed and some doesn't because of the difference in the file name format

Comment: Yup, that makes sense, sorry!